# Can I ask design-related questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Is Stack Overflow for design and architecture questions or just for technical questions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the [Help Centre "What's on Topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article.

In general - no. Such questions are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow (if your question doesn't have code, chances are good it isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow). It is suitable for **specific** programming issues.

You **can**, however, try posting on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), which has these in scope - though, please also check **their** [Help Centre "What's on Topic"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article **before** posting, as well as their specific meta topic about [design reviews](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260).

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking about design in the context of the user-interface, there's also [**User Experience**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Exchange. Otherwise, design meaning the technical side of 'designing software', you better refer to [**Software Engineering**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as Oded already answered.