# Where can we get a design review?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

I understand that [Code reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) have its area, but where can **Design reviews** be asked?  For example, "I'd like to design a generic service control interface, here is my plan" and get design idea feedback.

When we develop, we start out with at least some kind of high level plan.  So instead of showing actual code, I'm looking for a place to get design ideas, maybe a new stackoverflow site, to address the things that happen before coding begins.

Comment: consider checking [Design Review: on-topic or not?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6502/31260) and [Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6962/31260) at Programmers meta to see what would fly well and what wouldn't over there

Comment: see also [Can I ask design-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252139/can-i-ask-design-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmers is a site for software design.

Just make sure that the scope of your design question is sufficiently narrow, and not Too Broad.

Comment: hi @Servy would you know what exactly is the URL for the Programmers site?