# Does SO have place for design question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking to add a specific design functionality to a website and I was wondering if there's a Stack Overflow site where I can post these types of questions.

Comment: [graphicdesign.se]? [ux.se]? By the way, no site in the Stack Exchange network is a "forum".

Comment: see also [Where can we get a design review?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285521/where-can-we-get-a-design-review)

Answer (score 0):

SO does not; it is for programming specific questions.

However, SE has some that may be what you want.

[GraphicDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

[UserExperience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

As with SO and any other site/forum/etc... you might visit, you should read their help centers before posting anything.

You can peruse all [stackexchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/) or Google "< relevant topic > stackexchange" and usually find a SE site suitable for your needs for many topics.