# We shouldn't view [mvvm] as a model of a good tag (and should burninate it)

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

tl;dr the [mvvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvvm) tag is either a meta-tag that's irrelevant to the questions it's attached to, or a subject that's off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Either way, it should be burninated.

MVVM refers to the [Model-View-ViewModel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) software architecture.  It refer to a general architecture like MVC, MVP, etc. rather than any specific framework.  Questions with this tag tend to be either asking questions about how to apply this architecture, or are about software written using this architecture.

### Burnination criteria

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes and no.  Yes, if it's an off-topic, opinion-based architecture question.  Otherwise, no: it's a meta-tag that just describes the architecture the person's using.  This provides no useful information: it doesn't matter that you encountered your issue while implementing something in the MVVM architecture when the same problem would befall someone using an MVC architecture.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No.  Questions about software architecture/design are [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252139/208273) and [should be asked on Software Engineering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124867/165261).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not to any on-topic post.  Knowing the architecture someone is using doesn't help any more than knowing it's a [code-golf problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274984/208273).

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes.  As far as I'm aware, there's no framework named MVVM (a problem with the similar MVC tag).  However, as established above, the thing that it unambiguously means is off-topic.

### Number of questions

The elephant in the room: this tag, unfortunately, currently has 26,513 questions.  That's a lot, so that brings us to the next question:

> Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?

Yes.  It's bringing many opinion-based architecture questions to the site.  It doesn't take much scrolling through the list to [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62711387/208273) [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62684996/208273) [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62661545/208273) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62651403/208273) on the first page, and there are surely a lot more in those 26k+ questions.